# Google analytics Account Access management User last login

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am admin of Google analytics. I recently took over User access process and need to track last login of users to Google analytics console for my organisation.

is there any way to do this or run a report to show all users in Account access management and when they last logged in?

I searched all users and could not find a property of users indicating their last login date or time.